# pagination using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a datatable to show some information on page and I am binding a click event dynamically to the row of table. It works fine for the first page, but, when I navigate to the second page, the click event is not fired. I can not use .live() or .delegate() as my application is single page application and as per my knowledge these functions attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. So, can anybody please give me some suitable solution?

One of the solutions is to declare the click event before the datatable initiation.

Can somebody please provide me a working example for this solution?

Comment: This is why I recommend creating your own page system. It's very simple. There's an excellent video tutorial on how to do it here: youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 0):

Place your jquery actions in the  **fnDrawCallback** options of your datatable

```
$("#view_users_table").dataTable( { 

   "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $('.role_cell').css('width','60px');
   }
});
```